Heightmap creation from large landscape
I need to create a heightmap from a large terrain with many meshes (70k). It should ideally be quite detailed but I can settle for less if otherwise not possible. Ideally the heightmap resolution would be around 3000x3000. I am new to blender but open to complex solutions as well. Any tips on how to downscale such a map are also appreciated.

Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105283/create-height-bitmap-from-mesh ?

Well no, I am not asking how to bake a heightmap I am asking how to do so with a giant landscape that is made up of many thousands of meshes. Not just one terrain mesh.

Then maybe duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108052/generating-height-map-of-group-of-objects ? If not, it would improve your question to explain why these methods don't work for you.

Thank you, i found a way to split it into chunks and it is doable now.
